# How to Print Background Image Properly in Word 2003?

Tags: printing, background, ms-word, document

Issues: 
- Background image not being printed in Word.
- Background image not printed at the right scale.
- Background image resolution is blurry.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution if you are using Word 2003 and Illustrator/Photoshop. The finished document can be printed with other Word versions.

1. In illustrator/photoshop. Create a document at lettersize 8.5"x11".
2. Place your image/illustration and position it as you want.
3. Save for web and select png format.
4. Set width at 1650px (constrain proportion checked) and save.
5. Go to Word: Format/Background/Printed Watermark
6. Select picture water mark, browse and select the png file you just saved.
7. Set as 50% scale (this will make image sharper), and uncheck Washout. Apply and close.
8. You will now see your background image, and you can proceed with printing.